# Convert query result to string postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table which like this

```
TableA
id  data
--------
1  {"name":"abc","dob":"12-12-12","code""12O0X"}
2  {"name":"def","dob":"13-12-12","code""12O0Y"}
3  {"name":"ghi","dob":"14-12-12","code""12O0Z"}
```

I need name and dob data from this table which I get by running this query

```
select data->>'name' as name,
       data->>'dob' as dob 
from TableA 
where id='1';
```

My Output looks like this

```
name | abc
dob  | 12-12-12
```

But the catch is I want this data to be in string format like this

```
" "name" : "abc" ,"dob" :"12-12-12" "
```

so that I can convert it into hashmap. Is there a Postgres function that can convert my query result into my desired format.

Comment: What people typically do, is to read the JSON value as a String through JDBC (`ResultSet.getString()`, then use Jackson to convert that JSON string into a Map.

Comment: What database client library are you using in your code, in what programming language?

Comment: i am making making this query on Repository class and using JPA @Query annotation to write a native query in springboot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
select to_json(*)
from (
  select data->>'name' as name,
         data->>'dob' as dob 
  from TableA
  where id='1'
) result;
```

or

```
select json_build_object(
  'name', data->'name',
  'dob', data->'dob'
)
from TableA
where id='1';
```

or

```
select json_object_agg(key,val)
from TableA, json_each(data)
where id='1'
  and key in ('name', 'dob')
```

Comment: Is this going to return me a jsonObject or a String which looks like a json object?

Comment: All of these do return a `json` value. You can cast that to `text` if you need a JSON string.

Comment: Can i use this second query on JPA springboot @Query annotation or is it too complex.

Comment: @Umar I don't know about springboot, sorry